# Stop tasks until AlertController action occurs Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

I tried to execute a task from the `completion` parameter of `present` so that it would execute the desired function only after the `UIAlertController` closed. However, the function was called before the action was taken in the alert. How do I wait to execute the function until an action is taken?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wild Card Played", message: "Choose your suit", preferredStyle : .alert);
for suit in suits {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: suit, style: .default, handler: crazyEightPlayed))
                  }
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: cpuTurn) //Upon completion call the cpuTurn() function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem currently is that `cpuTurn` is being called when the alert is displayed to the user, not when the user pressed "Okay". As you can see in the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller) the completion function in the `self.present` method is "[executed] after the presentation finishes. This block has no return value and takes no parameters. You may specify nil for this parameter." The alert appears for the user, and the first UIViewController says "I have completed presenting the alert" and then runs the `cpuTurn` function.

You'll want to put the code in the handler of a UIAlertAction, which you appear to already have. You should move the cpuTurn call to the `crazyEightPlayed` function (or at least call cpuTurn from crazyEightPlayed)

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the view's subviews that have interaction. I would note those subviews, and then only activate those ones afterward.

Swift 2:

```
var disabledSubviews = [UIView]()

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
    for subview in disabledSubviews {
        subview.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { 
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if subview.userInteractionEnabled == true {
            disabledSubviews.append(subview)
            subview.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
var disabledSubviews = [UIView]()

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    for subview in disabledSubviews {
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}))
self.present(alert, animated: true) { 
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if subview.isUserInteractionEnabled == true {
            disabledSubviews.append(subview)
            subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```